# Funcion llamada dentro de otra funcion no funciona

Tags: c, funciones

Cuando mando a llamar la funcion Ambas_Dos() que a su vez llama las funciones Producto() y Division()
sólo manda correcto el primer parámetro, osea Producto(). Lo que me imprime para el parámetro División() es el valor "y" ingresado por el usuario al inicio y no la operación de la función.

En otras palabras:

Cuando se manda a llamar la función Division() por si sola, si hace la operación pero al mandarla a llamar dentro de la funcion Ambas_Dos() manda el valor de "y" definido por el usuario y no su resultado de operacion, a diferencia de la función Producto() que si lo hace bien al ser llamada dentro y fuera de la funcion Ambas_Dos(). ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Aquí mi codigo:

```
/* Escribir una funcion que llame a las otras dos funciones. */

#include <stdio.h>

float Producto(float a, float b);  // funcion 1
float Divisor(float a, float b);   // funcion 2
float Ambas_Dos(float a, float b); // funcion que llame a otras 2 funciones.

float x, y;

int main()

{

    /*PROGRAMA QUE CALCULA EL PRODUCTO Y LA DIVISION DE DOS NUMEROS */

    printf("Ingrese dos numeros: \n");
    scanf("%f %f", &x, &y);

    Ambas_Dos(
        x,
        y); // llamada de funcion que llamara a su vez a las otras dos funciones

    // Producto(x,y) = parametro x de Ambas_Dos(x,y)
    // Divisor(x,y) =  parametro y de Ambas_Dos(x,y)

    printf("El producto de %f y %f es: %.10f \n",
           x,
           y,
           Producto(x, y)); // Funcion Producto()
    printf("La division de %f y %f es: %.10f \n",
           x,
           y,
           Divisor(x, y)); // Funcion Divisor()
    printf("Llamado de la funcion Ambas_Dos es Producto(x,y): %f y "
           "Division(x,y): %f\n",
           Ambas_Dos(x, y));

    return 0;
}

// Declaracion de la funcion Producto
float Producto(float a, float b) {
    return (a * b);
}

// Declaracion de la funcion Division
float Divisor(float a, float b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        printf("Valor del segundo numero es invalido, no debe ser 0.\n");
    } else {
        return (a / b);
    }
}

// Declaracion de la funcion Ambas_Dos
float Ambas_Dos(float a, float b) {
    float c, d; // variables locales

    Producto(x, y); // parametro a = c = Producto(x,y)
    c = Producto(x, y);
    return c;
    Divisor(x, y); // parametro b = d = Divisor(x,y)
    d = Divisor(x, y);
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las funciones solo pueden devolver un valor, así que en tu función `Ambas_Dos`
no pasara del primer `return`:

```
float Ambas_Dos(float a, float b) {
    float c, d; // variables locales

    Producto(x, y);
    c = Producto(x, y);
    return c; // La ejecucion de tu funcion termina aqui

    // Este codigo no se ejecutara jamas
    Divisor(x, y);
    d = Divisor(x, y);
    return d;
}
```

Si quieres devolver mas de un valor puede que quieras utilizar un `struct`.